# Function pointers in C

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers

The following code (a function prototype):

```
void parse_ini(FSFILE *fp, void(*secFunc)(char*), void(*varFunc)(char*, char*));
```

presents errors when compiled:

```
util\setup.c:38: error: syntax error before '*' token
util\setup.c:38: error: 'parse_ini' declared as function returning a function
util\setup.c:38: error: syntax error before 'void'
util\setup.c:50: error: syntax error before '*' token
```

What is causing this? Using MPLAB C30, which is a version of GCC v3.23 for PIC24F/dsPIC 16-bit microcontrollers.

Comment: Your errors are from lines 38 and 50, but you only show one line of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd guess that you haven't included a header that declares/defines `FSFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
typedef void (*varfuncptr)(char *, char*);
typedef void (*secfuncptr)(char *);

void parse_ini(FSFILE *fp, secfuncptr *secFunc, varfuncptr *varFunc);
```

Comment: Don't you have an extra set of *'s there?

Comment: This is a workaround rather than a fix, and as aib said, you screwed it up.

Comment: And it still doesn't work because the bug is forgetting to define `FSFILE`.